# Is their goli in plant cell?

Tags: cell-biology

We know that plant cells have dictyosomes instead of golgi but in my book it was written that plant cells have golgi apparatus?

Comment: Please try doing these before posting a question:

1. Consider the fact that this is not really a chatroom and posts should be written using proper and clear sentences (we can help if your English is not great but please put in some effort).

2. There should be some research effort from the side of the asker (did you try looking up reliable sources?).

3. There should be some context and explanation (for e.g. "We know that..." and "my book says"; I am not sure which "we" are you referring to and which book you are reading)

Comment: I am reading my course book

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia > Golgi apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golgi_apparatus)

> The Golgi apparatus, also known as the Golgi complex, Golgi body, or simply the Golgi, is an organelle found in most eukaryotic cells.

and further

> In plants, Golgi stacks are not concentrated at the centrosomal region and do not form Golgi ribbons. Organization of the plant Golgi depends on actin cables and not microtubules. The common feature among Golgi is that they are adjacent to endoplasmic reticulum (ER) exit sites.

and also

> The [trans Golgi network] may act as an early endosome in yeast and plants.

The dictyosome is a part of the Golgi apparatus. There is no english wikipedia for dictyosome but [here is the french one](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictyosome)